# C# WPF route event from user control to MainForm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

so I'm coding an app that has (for now) one user control where I'm grouping some other elements. I would like to update the view when a property inside the User Control changes. I've tried to implement Inotify and it seemingly works (I've done it the same way in my main form, there it's fine). Also tried to set the binding in XAML but can't go through it somehow. I would guess I have to implement a routed event but I'm not sure if and how in that case.

What I noted is that I could remove some stuff from the OnPropertyChanged method but if I want to remove the now unassigned corresponding event, it states I'm not implementing INotify.

**XAML from User Control:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tool_WPF.frmLogin"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Fever_Tool_WPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Name="labLogin" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="150">
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LoginState, ElementName=labLogin}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Label.Content" Value="Success"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Label>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Forum username</Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbUser" Width="150"></TextBox>
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Forum password</Label>
        <PasswordBox x:Name="tbPassword" Width="150"></PasswordBox>
        <Button x:Name="cmdLogin" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Width="150" Click="cmdLogin_Click">Login</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**Behind code for user Control (property class)**

```
        public class StateLogin : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _loginState; // helping variable to trigger login state change

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int LoginState
        {
            get { return _loginState; }
            set
            {
                _loginState = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LoginState");
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name);
        }
    }
```

**Some of the main window XAML code**

```
<RibbonWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Fever_Tool_WPF"
    xmlns:Primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon" x:Class="Fever_Tool_WPF.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="589" Width="896"
    Initialized="MainWindow_Initialized">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Ribbon x:Name="ribbonMain">
        <Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
            <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Icons/MainWindow/help.ico"/>
        </Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
        <Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <RibbonQuickAccessToolBar/>
        </Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Icons/MainWindow/BlogHomePage.ico">
                <RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Information" ImageSource="Icons/MainWindow/Info.ico" Click="RibInfo_Click"/>
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <RibbonTab x:Name="rLogin" Header="Login" Visibility="Visible"/>
        <RibbonTab x:Name="rMPL" Header="MPL"/>
    </Ribbon>


    <local:frmLogin x:Name="frmLogin" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Visible"/>


    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" MinHeight="10" MaxHeight="20" Grid.Row="2">
        <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Image>
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Ping}" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Icons/MainWindow/StatusOffline_stop_32x.png"/>
                                <Setter Property="Image.ToolTip" Value="Can't ping the server."/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Ping}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="Icons/MainWindow/StatusOK_32x.png"/>
                                <Setter Property="Image.ToolTip" Value="Successfully pinged the server."/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

As said, I guess I'm missing somewhat on the routing (not routed at all^^), someone has an idea on this?

Comment: You should invoke your `PropertyChanged`-Event, and not only create event args ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `StateLogin`-Class to

```
public class StateLogin : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _loginState; // helping variable to trigger login state change

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public int LoginState
        {
            get { return _loginState; }
            set
            {
                _loginState = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LoginState");
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

You have to tell your your Event, that it should actually fire.

**Edit**

Assuming your DataContext and everything else is set right, you should try this for your UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tool_WPF.frmLogin"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="LoginRoot"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Name="labLogin" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="150">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=LoginRoot, Path=DataContext.LoginState}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Success"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Forum username</Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="tbUser" Width="150"></TextBox>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center">Forum password</Label>
            <PasswordBox x:Name="tbPassword" Width="150"></PasswordBox>
            <Button x:Name="cmdLogin" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Width="150" Click="cmdLogin_Click">Login</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

There is no need for a label, since you only use some Text. 
Also, i suggest you to have a deeper look on how XAML works. Placing a style as content is never a good idea.

Hope this gets you further. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for you reply, of course that's right. But somehow my UserControl (inside the MainWindow) still doesn't update the label. I think I'm having still some problem with my trigger.

Comment: @CuttingWide Modified your UserControl